# Mouse down,mouse move and mouse up event for an image?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to move an image with mouse?
`onmousedown` and `onmousemove` are the events to handle right?

```
  <html> 
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  funcion good()
  {
  document.getElementById("omna");
  document.getElementById("omna).style.position="absolute";
  document.getElementById("omna").style.top=somevalue; 'these keeps changing
  document.getElementById("omna").style.left=somevalue; ' these keeps changing
  }
  </script> 
  <img id="omna" src"/something.jpg" onmousedown="highlight() onmousemove="good()" onmousedown="stop()"> 'not working
  </body>
  </html>
```

How to use `mousedown` event on image? and with the `mousedown` event(I mean with the `mousedown` on the image), it should constantly run `mousemove` event function in JavaScript and when `mouseup` even occurs it should stop.
How do I loop through `mousemove` event continuously ? unable to make it out. I found some solutions on google but unable to figure it out the syntax and all. If somehow you post the same please explain me your solution.

Sorry forgot to tell you that my `mousedown` and the `mousevents` aren't working. Some people suggest use  anchor tag to that is that okay ? and why `mouseevents` are working for an image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

like this:

```
<html> 
  <head>
    <style>
      html,body {
        height:100%;
      }
    </style>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var omnaEl,dragData=null;
      function window_onload() {
        omnaEl=document.getElementById("omna")
        if(window.addEventListener) {
           omnaEl.addEventListener('mousedown',startDrag,false);
           document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',drag,false);
           document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',stopDrag,false);
        }
        else if(window.attachEvent) {
           omnaEl.attachEvent('onmousedown',startDrag);
           document.body.attachEvent('onmousemove',drag);
           document.body.attachEvent('onmouseup',stopDrag);
        }
      }


      function startDrag(ev) {
        if(!dragData) {
          ev=ev||event;
          dragData={
            x: ev.clientX-omnaEl.offsetLeft,
            y: ev.clientY-omnaEl.offsetTop
          };
        };
      }
      function drag(ev) {
        if(dragData) {
          ev=ev||event;
          omnaEl.style.left=ev.clientX-dragData.x+"px";
          omnaEl.style.top=ev.clientY-dragData.y+"px";
        }
      }
      function stopDrag(ev) {
        if(dragData) {
          ev=ev||event;
          omnaEl.style.left=ev.clientX-dragData.x+"px";
          omnaEl.style.top=ev.clientY-dragData.y+"px";
          dragData=null;
        }
      }

     </script> 
  </head>
  <body onload='window_onload();'>
    <img id="omna" src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRi-8XnnXwAZmz_5R5LHRHMNlnYYHCP4WqRdu6vhf_ru8wLK9XB3IrNrwix" 
        width="100px" height="100px" unselectable="on" style="position:absolute;user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are the right events, but a few things to keep in mind:

1. Don't use `onmousemove` style event bindings that need to be specified in the markup. Read this to get more background on [javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) event handling.
2. In conjunction with javascript, you will most probably need some help from **css**. Take it - don't rely on javascript to do all the heavy lifting.
3. If you're experienced with javascript (know how the language behaves) then I suggest you use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to do the heavy lifting (like event binding, attribute setting etc) - it will make your code more concise.

Cheers!