# IP camera PTZ control

Tags: javascript, html, ip-camera

I'm new in JS so sorry for this question :P , I'm building my IP Camera UI and camera has PTZ, after some time I relized that ptz work on this sistem, it sends comands throught URL, like this:

---

On mouse down - START Go down: `http://192.168.0.18:81/decoder_control.cgi?loginuse=admin&loginpas=&command=2&onestep=0&14000098822180.6339223394170403&_=1400009882221`

On mouse up - STOP Go down: `http://192.168.0.18:81/decoder_control.cgi?loginuse=admin&loginpas=&command=3&onestep=0&14000098826710.5439829423557967&_=1400009882672`

---

So my question is how can I make in JS that JS Code sends camand(I don't know how to call it) on mouse down/up but it does it all in background. What I mean when I say in background is that it doesn't go (loads new window) to that URL. Here is the screenshot so you can understand me better: http://prntscr.com/3ixk3q

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the mouse events part of javascript.
By having mouse events on mouse down you can redirect to your webpage or just send a request.

Take a look here on how to capture mouse events.
[Mouse down,mouse move and mouse up event for an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411180/mousedown-mousemove-and-mouseup-event-for-an-image)

To send an HTTP get request as you requested in your picture. Inside of your mouse down event call the GetCamerData() function.

```
    var xmlHttp = null;

    function GetCameraData()
    {
        var Url = url;

        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ProcessRequest;
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
    }

function ProcessRequest() 
{
    if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200 ) 
    {
        if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found" ) 
        {
            //not found 
        }
        else
        {
            // do stuff with request
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for your replay. How can I make it to run on mouse down one url and on mouse down second url?

Comment: do you mean mouse up and mouse down? Well you need to have 2 different functions. on your mouse up function call your mouse up function to get data. and on mouse down call your mouse down function